# Error "Invalid JSON primitive: models." on Kendo Grid datasource while passing model to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-datasource, kendo-ui-grid

Getting error while implementing Kendo Grid inline edit CRUD. When I add a new record and update it, I receive response code 500 with error:

I believe the problem is coming from `parameterMap`. What is the correct way to pass the model to the controller in Kendo?

> Invalid JSON primitive: models.

What are the models?

**Source Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var baseUrl = "/SomeUrl",
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: baseUrl + "/GetAccolades?profileId=" + @profileId,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: baseUrl + "/AddAccolade",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: baseUrl + "/UpdateAccolade",
                        type: "PUT",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                    },
                    delete: {
                        url: baseUrl + "/DeleteAccolade",
                        type: "DELETE",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            alert(kendo.stringify(options.models));
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProfileAccoladeID",
                        fields: {
                            ProfileAccoladeID: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                            ProfileID: { editable: false, nullable: false, defaultValue: @profileId  },
                            Years: { type: "string" },
                            Name: { type: "string" },
                            Level: { type: "string" },
                            Event: { type: "string" },                              
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        $("#accolades-grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: false,
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                { field: "Years", width: "150px" },
                { field: "Name", title: "Name", width: "150px" },
                { field: "Level", title: "Level", width: "150px" },
                { field: "Event", title: "Event", width: "450px" },                    
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
            editable: "inline"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddAccolade(ProfileAccolade accolade)
    {
        using (var db = new XXXEntities())
        {
            if (accolade != null)
            {
                var newAccolade = new ProfileAccolade()
                {
                    ProfileID = accolade.ProfileID,
                    Years = accolade.Years,
                    Name = accolade.Name,
                    Level = accolade.Level,
                    Event = accolade.Event
                };
                db.ProfileAccolades.Add(newAccolade);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new { Success = true });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Error occured" });
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I fix this error?

**Update:**

By removing `contentType: "application/json",` the error `Invalid JSON primitive: models.` is gone. However, the controller does not get the model.

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: What kind of JSON string result you get from `alert(kendo.stringify(options.models))`? Usually this problem occur after calling a method with URL encoded parameters instead of JSON string format.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695302/kendo-datasource-parameter-map

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto I got a well-formatted JSON string.

Comment: Try remove `contentType: "application/json"` from `create` and `update` section inside `transport`, since `application/json` forces request to follow JSON format, but what is actually sent is a plain JS object containing serialized `models`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem originated by usage of `contentType: "application/json"` inside both `transport.create` and `transport.update` part of `kendo.data.DataSource`. Since both operations use AJAX call (i.e. [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method), the `contentType` setting affects how type of request body will send.

By setting `"application/json"` content type, the request body will treated as JSON content, but actually `transport.parameterMap` returns URL encoded version containing `models` and formatted JSON string as key-value pair (KVP). This is why *"Invalid JSON primitive"* error occurs, because URL encoded format is not same as JSON format.

If you wish to keep `"application/json"` setting for AJAX call, add `JSON.stringify` method to convert URL encoded format of `models` as JSON data:

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
        return JSON.stringify({ models: kendo.stringify(options.models) });
    }
}
```

However if you want to send `parameterMap` as default content type (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), just remove all `contentType` definitions to set it back:

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     transport: {
         read: {
             url: baseUrl + "/GetAccolades?profileId=" + @profileId,
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "json"
         },
         create: {
             url: baseUrl + "/AddAccolade",
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json"
         },
         update: {
             url: baseUrl + "/UpdateAccolade",
             type: "PUT",
             dataType: "json"
         },
         delete: {
             url: baseUrl + "/DeleteAccolade",
             type: "DELETE",
             dataType: "json"
         },
         parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
             if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                 alert(kendo.stringify(options.models));
                 return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
             }
         }
     },
     // other DataSource definitions
});
```

Reference:

[kendo.data.DataSource (Kendo UI Documentation)](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#kendodatadatasource)

Comment: Thank you for the help. It did fix the error by removing "application/json". However, the controller does not receive the model passed from kendo. Any ideas?

Comment: I found solution here https://www.telerik.com/forums/parametermap---no-models-sent-to-controller-001b5bef1c02

Comment: Well, you're already have `batch = true` in `transport`, so the second solution (removing `contentType`) should work now. Is that your problem already solved, or something still missed?